# Bluetooth and card reader not working on Acer Aspire 255

Tags: 10.10, bluetooth, acer

I have installed ubuntu 10.10 on a new aspire d255 with atom N550 with 2.6.37 kernel that i had to install in order to use the inbuilt card reader.

There is another issue: I am not able to make  bluetooth connection. Simply I cannot activate it, when i push "activate" does not happen anything. May you help me
thank youbluetoo

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the relevant proprietary drivers from **System -> Administration -> Additional Drivers**?

Some pieces of hardware have **proprietary** drivers, which means that their source code is not available to Ubuntu developers. As such, you'll have to install them separately using the above menu option. Just open up the Additional Drivers window, select the appropriate driver and click "Activate" at the bottom of the window. The driver should get downloaded and installed automatically.